# The following set is open/closed?

Tags: general-topology

I am having difficulty in determining whether a given set is closed or open. (In higher dimensions.)

Set is the following:
$$\quad\{(x,y,x^3y^3): x^2+y^2<1\}\subset\Bbb R^3$$

Any explanations, strategies will help me much. I hope you understand my problem!

Comment: Before writing more on this particular case, it's reassuring to know that the graph of a continuous function on well-behaved (hausdorff) spaces is always closed!

Comment: As a general rule of thumb, open sets have the same dimension as the original space.  What you've written here has only two parameters and is living inside a $3$-dimensional space, so it will not be open.

Comment: @Jim I believe the set contains points of the form  $(x, y, x^3y^3)$ doen't it have $3$ parameters?

Comment: The points have $3$ coordinates because they live in $\mathbb R^3$, but the parameters are $x$ and $y$, there are only two of those.

Comment: No, the third slot is dictated by the first two.

Comment: @Jim Hmm ok I thought you were trying to say that the set is a subset of a plane, which would for sure be closed.

Comment: Also a general rule, BTW, is that things defined using $<$ or $>$ (as opposed to $\leq$ or $\geq$) are not closed.  So the intuition should be that you are expecting this set to be neither closed nor open.

Comment: If it was (x,y,z) instead of x^3*y^3, could we say the set is open? Or adding z term for ex, x^2 + y^2 + z^2 <1, now is open?

Comment: @YalçınCenik, yes the set of points $(x, y, z)$ with either the original condition on the domain or the new one that you've mentioned are both open sets in $\mathbb R^3$.

Comment: @Jim So thanks! How about closedness? If we also equality other than inequality, could we say the set is closed? İ mean we have 3 dimensions (x,y,z) and x^2+y^2+z^2 <= 1 ?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68636/discussion-on-question-by-yalcin-cenik-the-following-set-is-open-closed).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not open. Let your set be $A$. Let $\epsilon>0$. The point $(0,0,0)$ is in $A$. Do you see that $(0,0,\epsilon/2)$ is not in $A$? So we have that for all balls with middle point $(0,0,0)$ are not contained in $A$. Hence $A$ not open.

Edit: As mentioned in the comments, I forgot to address if it is closed.

It is not closed either. Take $(x_n, y_n)=(1-\frac 1 n,0) $. Extend this sequence as $(x_n, y_n, x_n^3y_n^3)$. This sequence is in $A$ for all $n$ but converges to  $(1,0,0)$ which is clearly not in $A$.

Comment: You haven't addressed closedness.

Comment: It's OK. But I search general idea actually. Taking a point and ball around it, seems no very effective all the time for complex(higher dimensions) sets I think

Comment: @amWhy is it okay, now?

Comment: Much better, thanks, @Sashi!

Comment: @YalçınCenik for disproving things like some set is open , I think it is very useful to just come up with an example where the definition of open set fails for that set. The same for closedness.

Comment: @YalçınCenik moreover, trying to visualize might help too in this case. You see that your set is just a graph in $\mathbb{R} ^3$ (so it has no volume) so you can never fit a ball in it.